# How to create a historical log of output from RTD Function

Tags: excel, rtd, vba

I want to store the value from a RTD function which is continuously changing. Suppose I set cell `A1 = SomeRTDFunction(`). How should I approach this?

One possibility I have in mind is maybe to create a `Sub` that runs continuously on some timer than copy the value from that cell and put it into another cell continuously.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think this thread answers your question:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397363/pause-rtd-server-in-excel-and-save-worksheet][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397363/pause-rtd-server-in-excel-and-save-worksheet

Answer (score 0):

This would update the `Range("A1").Value` with `Your_RTD_Function` every second.

```
Sub RunRTDFunctionContinuously()

    Dim nextSecond As Date

    nextSecond = DateAdd("s", 1, Now())

   'Your instruction below  

   Range("A1").Value = Your_RTD_Function

    Application.OnTime _
        Procedure:="RunRTDFunctionContinuously", _
        EarliestTime:=nextSecond

End Sub
```

Comment: My function is already outputting its value in A1. What I want is to create a log/chart of its value over time.

Comment: You can start an instruction that adds a `seriescollection` to a `chartobject` that you create and over every second the chart will update.